# Android on Virtualbox - Internet connection isn't available to all apps

Tags: internet, virtualbox

I've installed Android on Virtualbox. Everything works fine. As I started Android, I was able to insert my google username, browse the web, install application via PlayStore.

However, there are some applications I've installed that aren't able to use internet! They say that no internet connection is available.

I googled around, and I only found pages in which they solve the situation in which internet connection isn't available at all. But I did not find anything about my problem.

If other details are needed, please ask and I'll post them.

Cheers!

Comment: What applications don't work, and which ones do?

Comment: I believe many apps try and detect if your phone is connected via wifi or cell network, and consider themselves offline if neither is available.  In your case you'll be connected via virtual ethernet or NAT, which isn't a "regular" way for an Android device to be connected, so apps don't recognise it.