# Android x86 on VirtualBox - Apps cannot access internet

Tags: connection-issues, internet, android-x86, virtualbox

I recently installed Android x86 through VirtualBox onto my PC. It runs mostly fine (except for some weirdness with the mouse, which isn't really an issue) but for the fact that apps cannot detect the internet connection. I can access the internet through the included browser just fine, so I know that the connection is actually getting to the VM, but apps cannot access it.

From [Android on Virtualbox - Internet connection isn't available to all apps](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/62371/), I read that it's because I am using NAT or virtual ethernet that some apps detect that there is no WiFi or cellular and refuse to work. Is there a way to fix and/or get around this?

If it helps, my host OS is Windows 10 Educational and I will do my best to provide hardware specs if that would help solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to change network adapter settings (VirtualBox or VMware) from NAT type to Bridge type, that's it.

If you don't want to change the network type, there is another solution if your Android VM is rooted. I guess you can install the Xposed framework and install the Fake Wifi Connection module that works on Android 4.4 up to 5.1. If you have another version such as Marshmallow (6.0+), then you need to install an APK from here: https://www.mediafire.com/download/cbsu84p9496n70o. After installing it, you will be advised to install the hack module from Xposed so that it can make the APK work well.

---

For the mouse issue, you need to disable Mouse integration.

Comment: It's great that you're sharing your solution, but people don't want to download and install APKs from random places like Mediafire. That's a great way to end up with malware! Do you have an official, trustworthy source, or even a description of the APK so people can find it themselves?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was selecting in Settings -> Network -> Attached To: NAT -> Advanced -> Network Type: Paravirtualized

I could connect to internet, I even did log in in my Google Account in the Virtual Machine.

[image]